# How can I call @PreAuthorized method from service layer from reactive code with security context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring tell in FAQ's that best practice is to secure methods on service layer. But for me, it is have disadvantage because if call secured method not from Controller but from different service we will get 'An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext'. And Spring has comment regarding this on docs:

> If the method is not being called in the context of an HTTP request,
> you will likely need to handle the AccessDeniedException yourself

But I didn't found the right way how to do it. So, we need manually set security context. I have not found any best practices how to deal with it properly. So, asking how do you deal with it?

```
@Service
public class Service1 {
   
   @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority("ADMIN")
   public String method1 {
      //some logic
   }
}

@Service
public class Service2 {
   
   @Autowired
   private Service1 service1;

   @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority("ADMIN")
   public String method2 {
      //call service1 from reactive code(project reactor)
      Mono.just(id)
            .map(service1::method1)
      .....
      //An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
   }
}
```

UPD: The Service2 invoked by controller. Inside service2, serivce1 invoked from reactive code.

Comment: But how is Service2 invoked?

Comment: I would add a second method without security constraints and call this method in the secured one. No duplicate code, but two different methods. You could also propagate an authentication. If you use Google with keywords "schedule" and "Spring Security" you will find some solutions.

Comment: Added update that service2 is invoked by controller